# Google App Engine Tutorial Hello World Example won't run

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having difficulty getting to the starting line on my machine.
1) Windows 7 32bit all service packs installed
2) Installed JDK 1.7.0_21 
3) Checked PATH that only one copy of JDK\bin is in path and that it is correct.
4) Installed Eclipse Juno Java bundle. eclipse-java-juno-SR2-win32.zip
5) Install Google App Engine SDK per the tutorial using:
   https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
   Selected:
   - Google Plugin for Eclipse
   - GWT
   - SDK
   Did NOT select:
   - Developer Tools (Android)
   - Google App for Android 
   - NDK Plugins
6) Following the tutorial, pull down the Google Icon and select "New Web Application Project"
   - Name it Guestbook as shown
   - Uncheck GWT
   - Check Google App Engine
   - Finish
7) Following the tutorial, Run as Web Application

At this point, the console shows several successful steps and then crashes and burns with jetty unable to establish a loop back connection. The full console output is attached below.  I have searched all over the web and have not been able to find anything. I checked PATH and JDK. I checked the Windows firewall rule for Eclipse, it looks OK. I looked at the Classpath tab but could not see anything obviously wrong (although I don't know what it is supposed to look like)

### Full Console Output

```
Jun 15, 2013 2:56:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\User Data\Dave\Documents\Google App Engine Scratch\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jun 15, 2013 2:56:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed E:\User Data\Dave\Documents\Google App Engine Scratch\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Jun 15, 2013 2:56:51 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'E:\Eclipse Google App Engine\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.1\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'E:\User Data\Dave\Documents\Google App Engine Scratch\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Jun 15, 2013 2:56:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jun 15, 2013 7:56:52 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Jun 15, 2013 7:56:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector$1@15321fc: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
Jun 15, 2013 7:56:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
Jun 15, 2013 7:56:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed Server@150305e: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.<init>(SelectorManager.java:312)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:223)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:314)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:82)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I was able to absolutely nail the cause of this problem and fix it.

What I did was removed the JRE and JDK from "C:\Program Files\Java\" (which is where Oracle's installer puts them by default) and reinstalled them in "C:\Java\Java7\"  Apparently something in Eclipse and/or the Google Android development kit is still sensitive to spaces in the pathname to the JDK. This is an ancient general problem with Eclipse reported around 2005.

- I did NOT need to drop down to Java 6
- I did NOT need to edit Eclipse.ini and add a -VM line
- I did NOT need to manually add the path to the jdk to PATH

Hope this helps the next person because this is an incredibly frustrating problem when you encounter it.

Thanks!

David Hetherington

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Trying to run the 'Hello World' app using google eclipse plugin (eclipse - Kepler).

Solution: Adding to David's answer. If you have multiple jre's installed make sure the jre you are pointing to does not have a space in the absolute path. To change the jre you are pointing to go to eclipse - `window->preferences->server->runtime environments->google app engine->edit`. Now check the jre version you are pointing to. In my case I had `jdk 1.7` installed in `Program Files/Java` and `jre6` and `jre7` installed in the same location. I moved `jdk 1.7` to `Program_files` but was still getting the loopback error. Followed the above steps and pointed the jre version to the one in `jdk1.7/jre` in `Program_files/java` as earlier it was pointing to `C:/Program Files/java/jre7`
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have anything else running with the same PORT number as the web-application? Default webapplication PORT is 8888

Comment: I tried [netstat -a | find "LISTENING"] from a command prompt and nothing else seems to be on 8888

Comment: I also tried the run configuration option to "automatically select an unused port" no difference. (?)

Comment: On a different machine it runs fine. Problem machine = Win32/AMD processor. OK machine = Win64/Intel processor. Of course, the difference of Win32 vs Win64 makes me download all different bundles of both JDK and Eclipse tools... (?)

Comment: Hi. Seems to be a bug in the 32bit version: https://community.jboss.org/thread/222246?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t Try to upgrade the installs to the latest version in clipse